# How to verify if one chield exists in other table - SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two lists and I want to verify that a field in column X of table A exists in column X of table B.

If yes, enter in list A.
If not, insert it into list B.

```
List<class> A = new List<class>() { };
List<class> B = new List<class>() { };

var sameField = from rt in db.A join ot in db.B on rt.X equals ot.Y.
```

How can i make this?

***In table A, if in X column value is = "xpto" and in table B, in X column value is = "xpto"***

> go to List A

***if in table A, in X column value is ="xpto" and i table B, in X column value is ="aaa"***

> go to List B

Comment: Are these lists in-memory, or are you converting the Linq to SQL using something like Entity Framework?

Comment: @gunr2171 yes, using Entity Framework

Comment: @gunr2171 Why not just always return the object in List B?

Comment: @gunr2171 For what?